# how can i pause a macro wile IE generated file is open

Tags: excel, vba

My macro is generating a report in excel 2003 format from the Internet Application. Then I want to read that file and generate metrics from the data. While my excel file generated from the IE application, my macro executes beyond it can read that IE generated excel file. I want to pause my macro until IE generated excel file is complete.

I have tried the Application.Wait command but it stops generating the file until wait is over.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Post your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you posted your code, so we could see what you are trying.  But in the mean time, here is some code I wrote years ago, but should work for what you want to do.

```
    'This block holds the program until the output file is ready
OutFile = FilePath & "\" & yftTableFile

i = 0
Set fo = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Do Until fo.FileExists(OutFile) 'Loop until the output file is created, this could be infinity if there is a problem
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02")) 'Holds the program for 2 seconds
    DoEvents
    i = i + 1
    If (i = 30) Then
        MsgBox ("No output file created within 60 seconds")
        Exit Sub
    End If
Loop
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03")) 'Holds the program for 2 seconds to ensure the file is complete
```

Be sure you adjust the wait times and counters as required.

If this doesn't work and you know what the end of the file looks like, you could loop to the end of the file several times using a code like this:

```
file = FilePath & "\" & FileName 'Path to the initial temps file

fn = FreeFile
Open file For Input As fn

Do Until EOF(fn) 'Reading in the temperatures from the file

    Line Input #fn, InpLine
    IntTemp = Right(InpLine, 9)

    If (IntTemp <> "") Then
        OldTemps(i) = CDbl(IntTemp)
    End If

Loop

Close fn
```

Comment: Problem with this example is that file is not saved to anywhere. When the IE generates the file I get a new dialog whether I want to save or open the file. I get another dialog "File you are trying to open is not the same as file extension. ... trusted source before openning the file. Do you want to open the file?" with Yes, No, and Cacel button. When I click Yes it opens the file. I want to pause my macro until I click Yes in this dialog. My macro is not pausing. If I add Application.Wait then I do not get the two dialogs I mentioned above until the timer is over.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tiny routine that waits for the file:

```
C:\TestFolder\Newfile.txt
```

to be created.

The routine also allows the user to abort the wait by setting a value in cell **A1**

```
Sub WaitABit()
    FileIsThere = ""
    While FileIsThere = ""
        FileIsThere = Dir("C:\TestFolder\Newfile.txt")
        DoEvents
        If Range("A1") <> "" Then GoTo GiveUp
    Wend
GiveUp:
    If FileIsThere = "" Then
        MsgBox "Wait aborted"
    Else
        MsgBox "New file is ready"
    End If
End Sub
```